# Laravel AJAX pagination links

Tags: ajax, laravel, pagination

I'm returning LengthAwarePaginator to AJAX success and displaying it like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getLawsByFiltersElastic/0/' + types + '/' + years + '/' + keywords + '/' + result,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (result) {
            $("#law").empty();
            $.each( result.data, function( index, value ){
                $("#law").append(result.data[index].law_number);
                $("#law").append(result.data[index].law_year);
            });
        }
    });
```

My controller is like this:

```
        $page = Input::get('page', 1);
        $perPage = 10;
        $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;

        $paginator = new Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(array_slice($result, $offset, $perPage, true), count($laws), $perPage, $page, ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()]);

        return $paginator;
```

It displays only first page (10 records). I don't know how to display render links below data. Is there an easy solution?

Comment: You get only 10 records because your page always first. You should send page number in your request

Comment: @xAoc, ok i can send page number like $.ajax({
            url: 'getLawsByFiltersElastic/0/' + types + '/' + years + '/' + keywords + '/' + result + '?page=' + page, but how can I display links then?

Comment: Foreach them for example :)

Comment: Maybe you have some useful link that I can check so I can see how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e32dApb5yYI help you